# Part 2: How to correctly order segments by value, within an individual bar, on a bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

So I thought I had my question answered with [my prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61813491/how-to-correctly-order-segments-by-value-within-an-individual-bar-on-a-bar-cha), but alas something is still not working.  I am wondering if there is something in the structure of my data that I am missing because my prior question with fake data worked.

Here is a new reproducible example, with dummy data that more closely replicates my data set and my problem.  My question is how do I sort the segments ***within each bar*** of the bar chart by value (largest value within a bar on the bottom, smallest on top).

```
library(dplyr)

repro_df <- structure(list(Grp = structure(c(5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 
                                             4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 
                                             11L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
                                             5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 
                                             7L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
                                             3L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 
                                             6L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 4L, 
                                             10L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", 
                                                                                      "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), Segment = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                           Value = c(914, NA, NA, 228, NA, NA, NA, 207, NA, 179, NA, 
                                     NA, 149, NA, NA, 135, NA, NA, NA, 109, NA, NA, 105, NA, NA, 
                                     101, NA, 100, NA, NA, NA, 98, NA, 96, NA, NA, 87, NA, NA, 
                                     77, NA, NA, 74, NA, NA, 57, NA, NA, 49, NA, NA, 35, NA, NA, 
                                     31, NA, NA, 25, NA, NA, NA, 25, NA, NA, 21, NA, 18, NA, NA, 
                                     16, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 
                                     NA, 4, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                     0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
                                     NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
                                     NA, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -135L))

# Reorder the data frame
repro_order_df <- repro_df %>% 
  group_by(Segment) %>% 
  mutate(Grp = fct_reorder(Grp, Value))

head(repro_order_df, 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   Segment [3]
   Grp   Segment Value
   <fct> <fct>   <dbl>
 1 4     A         914
 2 6     B          NA
 3 1     C          NA
 4 2     A         228
 5 7     B          NA
 6 6     C          NA
 7 9     A          NA
 8 3     B         207
 9 3     C          NA
10 2     A         179

# Plot
ggplot(repro_order_df, aes(x=Segment, y=Value, fill=Grp)) +
  geom_col(color = "black")
```

When I graph this data after reordering, each bar is not ordered by Value as I would have expected.  A bit more oddly, in my real data set the first bar is ordered correctly but the following bars are not.  Any thoughts as to why this is not working?
[image: plot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Peter is definitely on the right track.  However, I understand the OP to be asking for the individual `Values` be ordered by `Value` within each `Segment`. I've made `Grp` a factor such that `Grp` is ordered in decreasing size of the largest `Value` in a `Grp`.  The code would look like:

```
  repro_ord <- repro_df %>% arrange(desc(Value)) %>% 
            mutate(Value_ord = row_number(), Grp = as_factor(as.character(Grp)) )
  p <- ggplot(repro_ord, aes(x = Segment, y = Value) ) +
            geom_col( aes( fill = Grp, group = rev(Value_ord) ),color = "black")

  bar_tot <- repro_ord %>% group_by(Segment) %>% summarize(Total = sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
          ungroup() %>% mutate_if(., is.numeric, round, 0) 

  p1 <- p + geom_text(data = bar_tot, aes(x=Segment, y = Total, label = Total), vjust = -0.5 ,
                   size = 3, hjust = 0.5, fontface = "bold" )
```

which gives.

[image]

This answer should be regarded as a long comment on Peter's answer rather than a new answer.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, having reread the OP question, It is very generous of you to consider your answer a comment; However, you should take the credit; What's more your answer is less convoluted!

Comment: One complication--I created a separate df to label the bar totals.  When I go to add that to the plot, I get an error saying `Value_ord not found`.   The code: `bar_tot <- repro_ord %>% 
  group_by(Segment) %>% 
  summarize(Total = sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate_if(., is.numeric, round, 0)
`   And then to plot:  `p1 <- p1 +
  geom_text(data = bar_tot,
            aes(Segment, Total, 
                label = Total,
                vjust = -0.5
            ),
            size     = 3,
            hjust    = 0.5,
            fontface = "bold"
  )
`

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the totals at the top of the bars.  You needed to move `fill` and `group` from `ggplot` to `geom_col` to keep them from being inherited by `geom_text`.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.  I tried `inherit.aes = FALSE` but must have had the syntax wrong.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

How about this, which I think is what you are after...

The trick is to utilise the `group` aesthetic combined with an additional grouping variable to control the plotting order and use the `Grp` variable to control the fill colours.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
```

#### Option 1) show merged groups in value order

create a new grouping variable to order the groups by segment and group size

```
repro_order_df <- 
  repro_df %>% 
  group_by(Segment, Grp) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Segment) %>% 
  arrange(Value) %>% 
  mutate(g = row_number()) 

p1 <- 
  ggplot(repro_order_df, aes(x = Segment, y = Value, group = g, fill = Grp)) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  ggtitle("p1 grouped by Grp") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

#### Option 2) show groups in value order with individual group values stacked largest first

create a new grouping variable to order the groups by segment and group size and value within group

```
repro_order_df1 <- 
  repro_df %>% 
  group_by(Segment, Grp) %>%
  mutate(Value_g = sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Segment) %>% 
  arrange(Value_g, Value) %>% 
  mutate(g = row_number()) 


p2 <- 
  ggplot(repro_order_df1, aes(x = Segment, y = Value, group = g, fill = Grp)) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  ggtitle("p2 grouped by Grp and Value") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Which give you:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>